# Using Val() Within Ajax Data parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am building my controls in an ASP.NET application with literal HTML injection. To do this, I am more specifically using the x-editable (http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) library. In the below example, **jQ** is a string I am building on the server side, **id** is a string representing the control id, and **method** is the method I am passing for the event.

```
 jQ += "$('#" + id + "').editable({" +
                      "url: function (params) {" +
                      "return $.ajax({" +
                      "type: 'POST'," +
                      "url: 'foo.asmx/" + method +"'," +
                      "data: JSON.stringify({" + id + ":$('#" + id + "').val()})," +
                      "contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'," +
                      "dataType: 'json'," +
                      "processData: false," +
                      "async: true," +
                      "cache: false," +
                      "timeout: 10000," +
                      "success: function (response) {" +
                      "  alert(response);" +
                      " }," +
                      " error: function () {" +
                      "alert('Error in Ajax');" +
                      "}" +
                      "});" +
                      "}" +
                      "});";
```

This actually all works great! Except, on this line:

```
"data: JSON.stringify({" + id + ":$('#" + id + "').val()}),"
```

the parameter in the corresponding webmethod always comes back empty. However, if I replace it with a constant, like this:

```
"data: JSON.stringify({" + id + ":'11111')}),"
```

And I see the 11111 on the backend. I tried the single quotes around the first way, no effect. No clue what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Step one would be to console.log `$('#" + id + "').val()`. It will return `''`, which will rule out the ajax request having anything to do with it. Simplify the example by removing the ajax request leaving just the console.log and continue debugging. You will likely find that the element either isn't an input, or doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used that library, but it looks like you instrument an `<a>` element so it's text can be edited when it is clicked on. Therefore, you should use `.text()` to get the value, not `.val()`.